# Command-line breakout?

Tags: command-line, gnome, software-recommendation, games

I love a good old game of breakout! Though I really hate GUIs and prefer TUIs and the command-line, so I was wondering if there is a command-line version of the game breakout? I searched in the Ubuntu Software Center but all I found was `kbreakout` which is not a command-line game, but rather a GUI one. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.18. This would be preferebly something from one of the repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub user [TheAlphaNerd](https://gist.github.com/TheAlphaNerd) has written a simple Curses version of Breakout in Python, which you can download from here https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheAlphaNerd/b3451c543de1ccb7b85d/raw/de65498536ed9a35cd9346a5bc395fc1d6258798/breakout.py

[image]

It only uses the Python standard libraries, and the file can be run from the command line without any installation by typing:

```
python <PATH TO FILE>/breakout.py
```

Comment: The link is broken, and breakout cannot be found in TheAlphaNerd's gists anywhere.